# Escaping Double Quote in FitNesse Variable Declaration

Tags: fitnesse

Escaping Double Quote in FitNesse Variable Declaration

E.g: Test "&" ABC, the result in the browser is Test & ABC

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
!define dq {double "&" quote}
${dq}
```

Displays like this:

```
variable defined: dq=double "&" quote
double "&" quote
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `!-` and `-!` for the special symbols.

And for your case it will be: `Test !-&-! ABC`.